# how to pass username and password with api in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an API. If you open that you should enter username and password. How can I  get the data which is in that API? If I write `get("....api-url....")`, it shows `unauthorized error`. How can I pass a username and password to that API?

```js
constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.getMyBlog();
}

private getMyBlog() {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:8088/.../...')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log(this.data);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming you want to send it along with the GET request as query parameters?

This is terrible bad practice (the users password is part of the URL - while the body contents may be protected by SSL, the actual URL will be fully visible to attackers) - read more @ https://www.fullcontact.com/blog/never-put-secrets-urls-query-parameters/

Also, the HTTP Module is being deprecated - look at using the HttpClientModule instead (https://angular.io/guide/http)

If you still want to do this:

```js
    public getMyBlog(username, password): Observable<any> {
      const params = new HttpParams().set('username', username).set('password', password);
      return this.http.get('...apiurl...', { params });
    }
```

For post:

```js
    public getMyBlog(username, password): Observable<any> {
      const body = { username, password };
      return this.http.post('...apiurl...', body);
    }
```

A better way for get requests is to send a token in the headers:

```js
    public getMyBlog(token) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token);
      return this.http.get('...apiurl...', { headers });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not getting data from api.

Comment: Is it your own API? Or a public one? If public, which is it?

Comment: Its activiti rest api

Comment: There are docs @ https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_installation_and_authentication - basically you do:this.http.get(`http://${username}:${password}@apiurl`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `` and then you can make around your string instead of ''.
**Also try to do something to encrypt your password before sending it.**

`public getMyBlog(username, password): Observable<any> {
   return this._http.get(http://localhost:8088/${username}/${password}`