# Angular 5 + Spring MVC/Rest - How to hide username and password from chrome developer tool in network tab

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I have implemented Login usecase with front end in angular 5 and api in spring mvc/rest.

when i login  with login credentials (username and password), i can see username and password in chrome developer tool inside request payload (POST method).

How to hide credentials from developer tool?

Answer (score 1):

You should send user credentials through secure [HTTPS connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). You will always see it in the browser, as it is by design, not secure alone.

Actually, that it is a good thing that you can see anything in the browser's dev tool what your app sends or recieves. By scrambling, or hashing the password won't make it more secure: anything that listens on the network can see it (and steal it).

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211633/how-to-pass-username-and-password-with-api-in-angular) for more info.