# Angular 5 get/post http with basic authentication

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, https

I had the following code to do a get http call without authentication and everything worked fine.

let headers2 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  his.http.get('https://api.test.com/account/get/',headers2).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.posts = data;});

But I don't know how to add in the above basic authentication, like this (in curl) but in ionic:

curl --user admin:password  -s -X GET "https://api.test.com/account/get/" -H "content-type: application/json"

Whatever I tried a take a 401 authentication error.

Thank you

Comment: Try https://user:password@api.test.com/account/get

Comment: It's not working for angular.... I tried this 

this.http.get('admin:password@api.test.com/account/get/',headers2).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.posts = data;

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211633/how-to-pass-username-and-password-with-api-in-angular

Comment: It's not the same, i use basic authentication, not token.

Comment: if you read that issue you will see that only the last part of the answer is about token...

Answer (score 1):

You can add basic authorization by appending it in headers, as below:

```
var headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
headers_object.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers_object.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("admin:password"));

const httpOptions = {
  headers: headers_object
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting 401 error...I used:

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic '+ btoa('admin:password'));

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS')

let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
this.http.get('https://api.test.com/account/get/',options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  ....

And the result...

Request URL: https://api.test.com/account/get
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 75.127.10.64:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 590
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Sat, 16 Jun 2018 19:02:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
Server: nginx
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected"
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.test.com
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36