# Not able to send Username and Password in Angular http request headers

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to send username and password as request headers (not query parameters) in a HTTP request.

I have the following `get` method written inside an Angular service.

```
 http.get() {
    let headers_object = new HttpHeaders();
    headers_object.append('username', 'Test');
    headers_object.append('password', 'Test123');

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: headers_object
    };
    const uri = 'http://localhost:8083/test';
    let res;
    this.http.get(uri, httpOptions)
    .pipe(map(data => data)).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res = result;
    });
    return res;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Network tab in Chrome DevTools]

Any help in this direction will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Ghan, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211633/how-to-pass-username-and-password-with-api-in-angular

Comment: Thanks @Bharat. It is for sending query params, any idea about sending them as request headers.

Comment: Think it's easier  to use post-Request instead of Get and send them in body

Comment: You should not send password and username as a password. It is insecure and bad practice. but If u really care ... read about setting custom headers

Answer (score 1):

Since [`HttpHeaders`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) is *immutable* (definition of an *immutable object* below:),

> An immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. - [*What are mutable and immutable data structures?*](https://benmccormick.org/2016/06/04/what-are-mutable-and-immutable-data-structures-2)

this means that you can only set it once within the same instance.

See below for an example:

```ts
let headers_object = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('username', 'Test')
  .set('password', 'Test123');
```

Comment: Nice explanation man! I believe thats the reason the approach I suggested works as well. And that also means to use append we need to do so at same time while creating new HttpHeaders().append(...) ...? Whats your thought on this?

Comment: IMO, it's a bit troublesome to keep on chaining methods. :) (Although you can set the initial headers in the `HttpHeaders` constructor: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#constructor())

Comment: Cheers mate! That's awesome.

Comment: @VishalGulati Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Its strange to be honest. The code looks fine and should have worked. To debug, could you try printing the headers object ins console and share what you see there?

Furthermore, Give the below way a shot:

```
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'username':  'Test',
  'password': 'Test123'
})
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I tried this and now it seems sending in the CORS headers(as this is a CORS request from one server to another) but response is not as expected. I mean it says the user is not authorized. although this user is valid and getting correct data in the same server where it already works.